# Difference between journaled and plain quota

Tags: mount, quota, journaling

I am trying to set up quotas on a filesystem and I am getting the famous message:

> quotacheck: Your kernel probably supports journaled quota but you are
>   not using it. Consider switching to journaled quota to avoid running
>   quotacheck after an unclean shutdown.

I have tried to find a link/source describing the differences between journaled and non-journaled quotas but I was unable to.

What are their differences and which one should be used when?

What is more, a mount option (which I cannot find documentation about) that should be used when creating journaled quota is `qfmt=vfsv1`.

What is this option?

Answer (score 3):

From this old [discussion thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxquota/discussion/57477/thread/e40d97e4/):

On boot kernel reads filesystem usage and limits information from `aquota.user` and `aquota.group` files stored on the respective filesystem when `quotaon` is run (e.g. from `init.d`). While system is up:

- In case of **plain quota** when new filesystem storage is being allocated to files or being released, quota information is tracked by kernel continuously but written to `aquota.*` files only when `quotaoff` or `quotasync` command (i.e. (`Q_SYNC` sub-command of `quotactl` syscall) are run (usually as a part of shutdown script).
- With **journaled quota**, the difference is that usage information in `aquota.*` files is being updated as a part of a filesystem transaction doing the space allocation.

If an unclean filesystem shutdown is detected during boot (e.g. if `/var/lib/quota/off` is not found on Debian systems because `quotaoff` wasn't run), it's very likely that filesystem usage and limits information in kernel memory could not be properly flushed to `aquota.*` files before shutdown.

- So in case of **plain quota** `quotacheck` is run which updates the `aquota.*` files with the actual usage information gathered by reading block allocation structures on the filesystem.
- While in case of **journaled quota** space usage information in `aquota.*` files is automatically updated when (`fsck` is run and) journal is replayed after a system crash. However `quotacheck` has to be run if (in addition to journal replaying) `fsck` finds some filesystem corruption (e.g. metadata inconsistencies recorded in superblock) and needs to fix it by modifying filesystem.

Note that in both cases if a system is booted with quotas disabled (or disabled after booting system), the usage information maintained by kernel will become and remain out of sync with the actual usage information, unless `quotacheck` is run - manually or as a result of unclean shutdown. `cron` jobs and `init.d` scripts are usually written to not perform `quotacheck` during normal working of a system or after a clean shutdown (see `quotacheck.mode` kernel command-line parameter).

> What is more, a mount option (which I cannot find documentation about) that should be used when creating journaled quota is `qfmt=vfsv1`.

It's the format of `aquota.*` files. From [kernel configuration](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.3/fs/quota/Kconfig#L60):

> config QFMT_V2
>   ...
>   This config option enables kernel support for `vfsv0` and `vfsv1` quota formats. Both these formats support 32-bit UIDs/GIDs and vfsv1 format also supports 64-bit inode and block quota limits.

And from [quotactl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html):

> Currently, there are three supported quota formats:
>
> - `QFMT_VFS_OLD` The original quota format.
> - `QFMT_VFS_V0`  The standard VFS v0 quota format, which can handle 32-bit UIDs and GIDs and quota limits up to 2^42 bytes and 2^32 inodes.
> - `QFMT_VFS_V1`  A quota format that can handle 32-bit UIDs and GIDs and quota limits of 2^64 bytes and 2^64 inodes.

Version 1 quota files (format `QFMT_VFS_OLD` or mount option `jqfmt=vfsold`, kernel configuration `QFMT_V1`) were named as `quota.*`. Version 2 quota files (format `QFMT_VFS_V0` and `QFMT_VFS_V1` or mount options `jqfmt=vfsv0` and `jqfmt=vfsv1`) support journaled quotas.